# Make Sending Alternate Username to Printer Queue Permenant

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, network-printer, cups, lpr

I am currently having trouble to print file to a userid protected network printer. The problem is that my username is not what they want.

Well, I can print files from terminal:

```
lpr -p [printer name] -U [alternate username] [filename]
```

Can I configure it from CUPS Web interface to make -U [alternate username] permanent for this printer?

Comment: did you find a solution for your problem?

there are similiar questions, but without a working solution:
http://superuser.com/questions/390906/
http://superuser.com/questions/387527