# How Can I Print Under A Username Different Than The One I'm Logged In As?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, printing, lpr

I bring my own personal laptop to school where my login is `nickname`. However, in order to print to the school's printers the username that sends the print job must match my school's AD login, `firstname.lastname`. Is there any way short of creating a `firstname.lastname` user on my computer to have print jobs sent to the school's printers have the originating login of `firstname.lastname`? For the record, my computer is running Ubuntu 10.04 and the school uses the lpr protocol to queue print jobs over the network.

Comment: did you find a solution for your problem?

there is also another similiar questions, but without a working solution:
http://superuser.com/questions/390906/

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a username with lpr as per [this question.](https://superuser.com/questions/352250/make-sending-alternate-username-to-printer-queue-permenant)

Ubuntu uses CUPS for printing so the easiest way is to use the web interface. You find it at: `http://localhost:631`. Change the URI for the printer to `lpd://firstname.lastname@SomeHostname/SomePrinter` or change the conf file in `/etc/cups/printers.conf` This will make it permanent.

A new user is not necessary.

Comment: If you try to add a username to the front of a URI CUPS removes it.