# Specify different username when printing to a lpr printer

Tags: windows, printing, lpr

My school requires me to use a different username than my Windows username in order to print. With Linux `lpr` I could just specify `-U username`, but there is no such option for Windows `lpr` (and even if it had, it still wouldn't be a "native support" -- I would love to print from Windows applications and not from the command line).

How can I make Windows to supply a particular username (different from my current username) when printing to a LPR printer?

I'm using Windows 7 x64, but that shouldn't matter much.

Comment: Can't test this now, but IIRC, if you can access the printer as Windows share, you could supply different credentials (similarly to when mapping a network share)

Comment: @lupincho: that is true, but Windows prompts me to install unsigned driver then ("Do you trust this printer?"). Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: Probably you could disable that warning, but I don't think that it is a good idea. You could just accept for this particular printer.

Comment: @lupincho: accepting doesn't seem like a good idea either because that amounts to installing untrusted code in ring0.

Comment: If you could find the printer make/model; you could install the drivers manually from the manufacturer website. Alternatively, some generic drivers could work.

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

How are you connecting to the printer? If you're connecting to it using IPP (a possible scenario if the printer is behind `CUPS`), you set the printer using an IPP URL. As IPP is made over HTTP, you could try good old `ipp://user@host/...` (and IPP allows SSL (so HTTPS), but I guess that depends on the server configuration).

Comment: I use Linux (Fedora 20) and the cups server remove the username@ after I save it (tested with gnome-control-center, system-config-printer and CUPS webinterface). I can use lpr -P printer -U user with no hassle, but would love to print directly from the applications.